# How do i DOM manipulating within ajax call and event handler

Tags: javascript, ajax, autocomplete

I having a autocomplete function based on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete) example.

In my solution i like to exchange the countries array to a array which is served by an ajax call. The items are correct loaded and displayed, but the keydown event and the manipulating of css class are not done or rather not displayed. Here is my code:

EDIT: Try to make clear of my problem: The linked example works with a defined array of countries which is given as parameter into the autocomplete function. But, i wish to create the array from a rest service which will be called by the ajax call.

My problem is, on the event 'KEY DOWN' the items are not highlighted as the manipulation of div items suggests (see method addActiv()).

And i'm not sure where the problem is. Can it be a problem of making ajax call within an eventlistener?

```
<script>
function autocomplete(inp) {

            var currentFocus;
            /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
            inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
                var a, b, i, val = this.value;
                if (!val) {
                    return false;
                }
                currentFocus = -1;
                a = document.createElement("DIV");
                a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
                a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");

                this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'http://localhost:8080/find/' + val.toLowerCase(),
                    dataType : 'json',
                    type : 'GET',
                    success : function(data) {
                        if (data) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                if (data[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
                                    b = document.createElement("DIV");
                                    b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + data[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
                                    b.innerHTML += data[i].substr(val.length);
                                    b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + data[i] + "'>";

                                    b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                                        inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                                        closeAllLists();
                                    });
                                    a.appendChild(b);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    },
                    error : function() {
                        console.log('Error call for '+ url);
                    }
                });//end ajax
            });//end addEventListener


            /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
            inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
                    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
                  if (x){
                      x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
                  } 
                  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                    /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
                    increase the currentFocus variable:*/
                    currentFocus++;
                    //console.log("currentfocus: " + currentFocus + " " + x[currentFocus].classList);
                    /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
                    addActive(x);
                  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
                    /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
                    decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
                    currentFocus--;
                    /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
                    addActive(x);
                  } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (currentFocus > -1) {
                      /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
                      if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
                    }
                  }
            });

            function addActive(x) {
                /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
                if (!x) return false;
                /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
                removeActive(x);
                if (currentFocus >= x.length){
                    currentFocus = 0;
                }
                if (currentFocus < 0) {
                    currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
                }
                /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
                x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
            }

            function removeActive(x) {
                /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                  x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
                }
            }

            function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
                /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
                except the one passed as an argument:*/
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
                console.log('cloasAllList');
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
                        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
            document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                closeAllLists(e.target);
            });
        }


        autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"));
       </script>
```

I'm not sure if it will work with an ajax call inside an event handler or if i need to call the ajax seperately. Logging output in console shows me the triggering of key down correctly, but the items in the divs are not highlighted.

How can i correct the code?

Comment: lot of code, and still i am not getting what you are asking.can please explain more.

Comment: side note : for better readability/best practices move your ajax success code to a method and call that from the success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. 
The problem was the continous added list from ajax call which results in an huge amount of div elements with dead references. A clean up of the list before the ajax call and creating the div element resolves the problem.